# Как сделать возврат к ответу на вопрос в случае неправильного ответа на него?

Tags: python

Скажите пожалуйста, какая ошибка в коде, и если можете, поясните как можно сделать возврат к ответу на вопрос в случае неправильного ответа на него

```
import time
questions = 0
correct_answer = int(o)

def welcome():
    print('Привет, ты попал на очень крутую квиз-игру.\nПредставься, как тебя зовут?')
    name = str(input('Введи своё имя:' ))
    print('Привет,', name + ' :')
    time.sleep(1.5)
    print('Итак, первый вопрос.')
    time.sleep(1)
    questions = input('В каком году вышла игра Minecraft?: ')
    if questions == 2011:
        correct_answer += 1
    elif questions == 'Две тысячи одиннадцатый год':
        correct_answer += 1
    else:
        correct_answer =+ 1 and print('Неверно, попробуй ещё раз.')
        
welcome()

if __name == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: основная ошибка в том, что вы код в виде картинки прикладываете

Answer (score 2):

```
correct_answers = 1

def func():
    global correct_answers
    correct_answers += 1

func()
print(correct_answers)
```

без указания `global` питон будет считать переменную локальной, а у вас нигде внутри функции переменная `correct_answers` не инициализируется, поэтому и возникает ошибка

при указании внутри функции `global` питон считает, что переменная глобальная и ищет ее "снаружи"

ну и вторая ошибка - использование результата функции `print` в своей логики

```
correct_answers -= 1 and print(...)
```

функция `print` не возвращает значение (т.е. возвращает `None`), поэтому

```
correct_answers -= 1 and print()
```

равносильно

```
correct_answers -= 1 and None
```

а это будет приводить к ошибке

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'int' and 'NoneType'